# How do you trace and visualize JavaScript Promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, promise

In writing a fairly large JavaScript module with lots of async operation all dealing with promises, it becomes quite difficult to debug and follow the flow/state of promises.

Are there any tools or frameworks for instrumenting tests or module code to give he a flow of all the Promises in my system? I'm using jQuery promises if it matters at all.

Comment: +1 excellent question. I have written my own promises library where all promises are stored in a single array for easy looping and debugging. I'd be interested to understand how it works in jQuery. btw the question is closed, I voted to reopen it.

Comment: @Christophe don't vote to reopen a question because you think it can be usefull. No every usefull question can be asked on StackOverflow. Questions asking for 'best tools/tips/tricks' are really open-ended and if questions can't have one correct answer, they do not belong to a Q/A site as StackOverflow.

Comment: This question, while useful, doesn't really belong to Stack overflow. Try [programmers.se] (flag to migrate)

Comment: @Wouter I understand your point, and maybe the OP could have chosen a better wording. As I said I have done some work with promises, and I see this question as very code-oriented and specific. I would expect an answer along the lines of "in jQuery the status of promises is stored in an array called $.xxx" or "in jQuery the function $.yyy allows you to loop through all promises".

Comment: Any suggestions on a better rephrasing?  This is hard because I'm looking for hopefully a framework that I don't know about. There's a chicken and egg issue here, where I can't be more specifica as I am asking about something I'm unable to find.

Comment: @Christophe: You're wrong. The FAQ explicitly states that questions about software tools commonly used by programmers belong here. If you want to change the FAQ open a discussion on meta.stackoverflow. This question actually qualifies for 2 reasons. First it's a question asking for debugging tools (note that it's not a poll, just a query if such a thing exist). Second it's a concrete answerable question about a real problem faced by this developer.

Comment: @slebetman sorry about that, I'll delete the comment. Note that I was the first one to vote to reopen the question, I have no doubt that the question belongs here (see my other comments).

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, and stimulated by @MrLeap's idea to send messages to the `console`, how about a creating Deferreds via an "adapter" of your own design.

eg (embryonic and untested) :

```
var debugMode = true;

function DeferredAdapter(name) {
    var dfrd = $.Deferred();
    if(debugMode) {
        dfrd.notify = function() {
            console.log(name + ': notify');
            if (arguments[0] && typeof arguments[0] == "string")
                console.log(arguments[0]);
        };
        //similar for resolve
        //similar for reject
    }
    return dfrd;
}
```

This way (when you've got it working), you can do extra stuff when debugging, with a simple mechanism to turn off the extra stuff in production code, without the need to go through all your code purging `console.log()` statements.

Answer (score 1):

It would add quite a bit of development overhead, but if you're using node for the back end you can implement pretty robust asynchronous unit tests with [vows.js](http://vowsjs.org). If you want to add even more work for yourself you could use vows to create mock versions of all your responses if you're using some other kind of server tech, and use it for testing and reporting. Using a node.js mock server also lets you do robust, enterprise^^ things like simulate certain requests failing to see how gracefully your front end responds to it.

I wish I had a better answer than this though; `console.log` and `console.dir` are your best friends. Cram your callbacks full of them so you can get an idea how long stuff takes to happen, and in what order they happen.